# Count unique rows on enum type column to output two more columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I have following mysql table:

```
Item Name   Listing Fee Listing Type
watch       $0.20       LISTED
watch       $0.20       LISTED
watch       $0.30       SOLD
glasses     $0.50       LISTED
glasses     $0.50       LISTED
glasses     $0.50       LISTED
glasses     $1.00       SOLD
```

What I require is below output by a Group by SQL:

```
Item Name   Total Fee   Total Listed    Total Sold
watch       $0.70       2       1
glasses     $2.50       3       1
```

The rule is that each "Item name" will having multiple records of listing, where fee and listing type is defined. There could be two "listing type" [LISTED & SOLD].

I want to run a query on the table and generate the summary like output mentioned.

thanks
wikki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    `Item Name`, 
    SUM(`Listing Fee`) AS `Total Fee`,
    SUM(CASE `Listing Type` WHEN 'LISTED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Total Listed`,
    SUM(CASE `Listing Type` WHEN 'SOLD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Total Sold`
FROM `Table Name`
GROUP BY `Item Name`
```

This will summarize the list using static "Listing Types". If you want a dynamic list, you would have to build the SQL in a stored procedure, and execute it.

Output:

```
Item Name   Total Fee   Total Listed   Total Sold
watch       $0.70       2              1
glasses     $2.50       3              1
```

You could take this a step further:

```
SELECT
    `Item Name`,
    SUM(
        CASE `Listing Type`
            WHEN 'LISTED' THEN `Listing Fee`
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS `Total Fee Listing`,
    SUM(
        CASE `Listing Type`
            WHEN 'SOLD' THEN `Listing Fee`
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS `Total Fee Sold`
FROM `Table Name`
GROUP BY `Item Name`
```

Output:

```
Item Name   Total Fee Listing   Total Fee Sold
watch       $0.40               $0.30
glasses     $1.50               $1.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly - you should group these records by items, then to count totals you can use a small trick -

```
SELECT
  `Item Name`,
  SUM(`Listing Fee`) `Total Fee`,
  COUNT(IF(`Listing Type` = 'LISTED', 1, NULL)) `Total Listed`,
  COUNT(IF(`Listing Type` = 'SOLD', 1, NULL)) `Total Sold`
FROM
  mytable
GROUP BY
  `Item Name`;
```